# OTR and/or SecureIM library for C# .NET

Tags: privacy, .net, instant-messaging

I'm looking for implementations (or even wrappers) for [OTR](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/#downloads) or [SecureIM](https://code.google.com/p/secureimplugin/) encrypted chat protocols usable from C#.

Currently I found none, and considering porting Java OTR library and/or wrapping SecureIM. But maybe I missed something?

Comment: SecureIM is written in C++ and callable from C#...  what is the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Phone 8 apps, at least from "mere mortals" (Skype, Adobe Reader etc are exception from this rule) can't have unmanaged assemblies, as that would violate the sandbox model

Comment: If you can't have unmanaged libraries, then why are you asking for wrappers?

Comment: To be able to prototype UI and so on whilst porting crypto to managed code

Comment: I expect you already checked the [OTR library and toolkit on CyberPunks](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/index.php#downloads)? It includes both C++ and Java source code, has [ample documentation](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/index.php#docs)  with well defined [protocol and crypto](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/Protocol-v3-4.0.0.html), [user authentication (PDF)](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/~iang/pubs/impauth.pdf), and the source code is installable from a [git repository](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/index.php#git)?

Comment: @TidalWave You do realize my question already includes exact same link, do you? :)